# Dapp connector for cardano-cli wallets

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, decentralized-applications

I've read about the Yoroi dapp connector, but is there a way to connect a wallet which was created with cardano-cli to some dapp?

Comment: I tried yesteard i would try with Nami but you must convert your Keys to one compatible with Cardano Serialization Lib, I read that they are compatible here https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/doc/getting-started/generating-keys.md but i do not know how to use the CBOR in the cardano-cli keys for doing this, but if you start with your 24 words phrase in Cardano-cli, you could use that same 24 words in the Cardano Serialization-Lib, follow the instructions in the page above and connect to Nami.

Answer (score 0):

`cardano-cli` uses a different way to generate from th other wallets Daedalus or Yoroi.

The creation of the keys via `cardano-cli` does not include the step of derivation from bip39 mnemonics entropy - which is a prerequisite for using it in other wallets.

Although all the keys conform with the same `bip32-Ed25519`, `cardano-cli` do not allow to be recovered via the seed phrase.

It is possible to convert the keys in other direction:

mnemonic-bip39 keys -> cardano-cli vkey/skey format